# Given a history of actions of the same kind, how can I count # of actions before/after certain points in time, provided in a separate table?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have two tables with data about people.

- One table holds a log of cash deposits at the ATM per person.
- Other table tracks meaningful life events per person.

For each person, I want to *count* how many cash deposits were before and after each life event. I run this query on AWS Athena/Presto.

### Data Example

```sql
WITH life_events(person_name, life_event, event_time) AS (
    values 
    ('john',   'ten_year_anniversary',          date('2016-03-02')),
    ('john',   'got_fired_from_ibm',            date('2019-01-17')),
    ('john',   'purchased_first_lamborghini',   date('2023-02-10')),
    ('jane',   'got_flight_license',            date('2017-04-04')),
    ('jane',   'first_child_born',              date('2020-10-10')),
    ('daniel', 'college_graduation',            date('2010-07-09')),
    ('daniel', 'first_job',                     date('2020-10-30'))
),

log_of_deposits(person_name, time_of_deposit) AS (
    values
    ('john',   date('2015-01-07')),
    ('john',   date('2016-01-30')),
    ('john',   date('2017-10-10')),
    ('john',   date('2018-04-10')),
    ('john',   date('2020-03-23')),
    ('john',   date('2023-05-12')),
    ('jane',   date('2018-09-15')),
    ('jane',   date('2018-11-12')),
    ('jane',   date('2019-05-23')),
    ('jane',   date('2021-09-09')),
    ('jane',   date('2022-08-10')),
    ('daniel', date('2009-01-15')),
    ('daniel', date('2010-03-20')),
    ('daniel', date('2015-10-12')),
    ('daniel', date('2016-09-09')),
    ('daniel', date('2018-02-03')),
    ('daniel', date('2019-12-01'))
)
```

*Desired Output*

```
+-------------+-----------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| person_name | life_event                  | n_deposits_before | n_deposits_after |
+-------------+-----------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| john        | ten_year_anniversary        | 2                 | 4                |
| john        | got_fired_from_ibm          | 4                 | 2                |
| john        | purchased_first_lamborghini | 5                 | 1                |
| jane        | got_flight_license          | 0                 | 5                |
| jane        | first_child_born            | 3                 | 2                |
| daniel      | college_graduation          | 2                 | 4                |
| daniel      | first_job                   | 6                 | 0                |
+-------------+-----------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

Is there a straightforward way to do it in *SQL*, and specifically in Athena/Presto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved with two correlated subqueries that perform the after/before count of deposit for each life event, as demonstrated by @tsilb. A *possible* downside of the technique is that it might not scale well against a large dataset, since the subqueries need to be re-executed for each user event, resulting in the same deposit rows being scanned multiple times.

One alternative is to use window functions. The basic idea is to consider a deposit as a life event; we can generate a dataset that combines both with `union all`. Then, a window count gives us how many deposits happened in the same user partition, before or after the current row. The last step is to filter out deposit events.

Assuming that an event name such as `'_deposit'` will never clash with your actual life events data:

```
select *
from (
    select l.*, 
        count_if(life_event = '_deposit') over(partition by person_name order by life_event     ) n_deposits_before,
        count_if(life_event = '_deposit') over(partition by person_name order by life_event desc) n_deposits_after
    from (
        select person_name, life_event, event_time      from life_events
        union all
        select person_name, '_deposit', time_of_deposit from log_of_deposits
    ) l
) l
where life_event is distinct from '_deposit'
```

Or we can make it safer by using a separate column to identify deposits:

```
select *
from (
    select l.*, 
        sum(is_deposit) over(partition by person_name order by life_event     ) n_deposits_before,
        sum(is_deposit) over(partition by person_name order by life_event desc) n_deposits_after
    from (
        select person_name, life_event, event_time     , 0 is_deposit from life_events
        union all
        select person_name, null,       time_of_deposit, 1            from log_of_deposits
    ) l
) l
where is_deposit = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select e.person_name, e.life_event,
    n_deposits_before = (
        select count(0)
        from log_of_deposits d
        where d.person_name = e.person_name
            and d.time_of_deposit < e.event_time),
    n_deposits_after = (
        select count(0)
        from log_of_deposits d
        where d.person_name = e.person_name
            and d.time_of_deposit > e.event_time)
from life_events e
```

And of course decide what to do about =.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with old-school grouping and aggregation:

```
select life_events.person_name,
       life_events.life_event,
       sum(
           case
               when log_of_deposits.time_of_deposit < life_events.event_time then 1
               else 0
           end
       ) as n_deposits_before,
       sum(
           case
               when log_of_deposits.time_of_deposit > life_events.event_time then 1
               else 0
           end
       ) as n_deposits_after
from life_events
join log_of_deposits
on life_events.person_name = log_of_deposits.person_name
group by life_events.person_name, life_events.life_event;
```

Explanation

- we join `life_events` with `log_of_deposits` by `person_name` (let's hope every `person_name` is `unique`)
- we `group by` the `person_name` and the `life_event`
- so each `life_event` forms a group and is paired with all `log_of_deposits`
- the first two fields of the `select` clause is self-explanatory
- the third and the fourth element is the sum of the criteria match, i.e., the numbers we are searching for

I have used strict comparisons of `<` and `>` for `n_deposits_before` and `n_deposits_after`, respectively, feel free to change them to `<=` and `>=`